# new Dailymotion player API: programmatically set playback quality

Tags: javascript, dailymotion-api

I want to force the Dailymotion player to *always* show the highest resolution available for any given embedded video. If you manually set the player to 1080p during a video with that resolution available, and the next video in the playlist is only available in 240,380,480 then you get 380p (so you need to click 480, again, manually). If you manually set the playback to "optimal", then you often get a truly suboptimal resolution.

The old player API supported setting the playback quality via `setPlaybackQuality` (as per the player on many other sites). The new player doesn't seem to support this anymore.

How to either:

a) set the playback quality via JavaScript?, or

b) configure the embedded player to *always* play the highest available resolution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the **`quality`** parameter in the player API to set the playback quality? The description of this parameter is as follows:

> Determines the quality that must be played by default if available. Valid values are: 240, 380, 480, 720, 1080 (defaults to 380)

(source: http://www.dailymotion.com/doc/api/player.html)

Hence if you set the quality to 1080, if will play this quality if it is available, otherwise it fallbacks to 380.

edit: if you want to know the highest available quality before setting it in the player, you can perform an API request to the `available_formats` fields. Test with:

```
https://api.dailymotion.com/video/VIDEO_ID?fields=available_formats
```

Comment: Correct  me if I'm wrong... but you can only set that *before* the video plays? (Not during playback). That would mean I'd have to know the max available resolution for the video in question before I play it... very difficult for an playlist managed through your site but embedded on mine.

Comment: And `380` is a very annoying fallback when the video has `480` and `720` available.

Comment: You old player was much more flexible in this regard, as is the current YouTube player.

Comment: you're right, this behavior should be fixed in the coming weeks. In the meanwhile, you can use the API to know available formats as I added as suggestion in the post above

Comment: I can't use that particular API unless I key a key, no?

Comment: yes, you have to register as a developer and request an API key at http://www.dailymotion.com/profile/developer using your dailymotion account. You will find some documentation at http://www.dailymotion.com/developer

Comment: So that makes it very hard to distribute this code to run on other sites similar to mine. I either need to provide a web-service to them (probably against your terms) or they each need a key.

Comment: Actually, forgot my previous comment, you don't need an API key for such a request, test https://api.dailymotion.com/video/VIDEO_ID?fields=available_formats by replacing VIDEO_ID with a valid video id You can read the documentation at http://www.dailymotion.com/doc/api/obj-video.html

Comment: Ok, so that works but gives back `quality` values from the *old* API :-) I'll just translate those to the resolutions required by the new API.